# How to play Magnatune.com songs in Amarok via DBus

Tags: amarok, dbus

Amarok implements MPRIS DBus-based protocol for remote control. How can I use it to play http://magnatune.com songs? Basically, how does a Magnatune song URI look like from Amarok point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example song URI for Magnatune for a paying subscriber would look like this:

http://username:password@download.magnatune.com/all/03--Massassi%20Morning%20Star--Ishwish_nospeech.mp3

Further details about the Magnatune API are on their [API page][1]. The documentation is sparse there, but you can download the "zip" files linked to there, which can XML files, which have a structure which is fairly clear.

Comment: I have used qdbusviewer to verify, that amarok indeed uses normal HTTP URLs in the MPRIS interface. Thanks.